# SQL Server : Load CSV without BULK load statement

Tags: sql-server, csv

I'm blocked from using the `BULK` statement in SQL due to company security measures.  Even the simplest query doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\path\to\csv\myCSV.csv', SINGLE_CLOB) AS csvTable
```

I get the error:

> You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

I see a couple SO questions about this but not much in terms of answers. I'm wondering if there's a way around this where I could load the CSV file into SQL Server as a single string and then parse it line-by-line, inserting each row into a temporary table.

Is this a possibility or can anything else be done?

Comment: Is  "path\to\csv\..." a file on your local machine, or a file on the SQL server machine? I think you might see that error message if the path isn't a file on the sql server machine.

Comment: The path is on my local machine.  I need to access specific data that's on my machine.

Comment: Of course there is. Use a proper ETL tool - even BCP. But your mgmt has blocked your current approach for some reason so perhaps should have a discussion with the dba and your superiors where you can justify your need.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah The SqlServer instance isn't running on your local machine though, right? So, how is SqlServer supposed to know where "C:\path\to\csv\myCSV.csv" is? It will look for a file at that path *on the server*, which won't exist and so you'll see this issue. As SMor suggested, use BCP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Okay, I would have expected SQL Server to interpret the filepath relative to my machine (even though it's a remote server), so thanks for that clarification.  I imagine it could be messy, but if I simply paste the raw CSV text into the query (or maybe to another query file and import it - although the filepath issue might prevent that as well), could I still parse it and I suppose iteratively add it to a temporary table?  Just a lot of red tape to go through when it comes to system access so I'm just looking for an approach that minimizes that.

Comment: @SMor I believe bcp needs the `bulkinsert` permission anyway. But yeah, there are loads of tools out there

Comment: Also, don't _parse it line-by-line_ because that would be wrong. CSV is not a line-by-line format, it's a character based state machine where fields can have data that include embedded comma, quote and linebreak characters - meaning that fields can span multiple lines. As others said above: find a tool that can parse CSV files for you and insert the data.